# iOS Safari doesn't update CSS

Tags: css, safari

A lot of people visited my site but I've done a lot of changes in the CSS files recently.

However, on iOS Safari, people are stuck with the "first" version of the CSS file. I've tried to add a version at the end of filename, change the filename but it doesn't help.

Is there a way to force user to load the last version of the CSS because today, all my first visitors are stuck with display errors.

Comment: Just change the name of the file you want updated.

Comment: I did and replaced style.css with style1.css but didn't work either...

Comment: If that's the case, there's ***absolutely nothing*** you can do, because it sounds like your browser doesn't even load the website, it just shows a cached version of it. Therefore, no matter what you change on the website, it's not going to get loaded, is it? You might want to try [refresh-your-cache/ios](https://refreshyourcache.com/en/ios/).

Comment: Of course it works when I delete the cache in the Settings. But the problem isn't me, it all my "old" visitors. I can't show a popup telling them to clear the browser cache.

Comment: Running into same issue, would love to hear if anyone found a solution

Comment: @Suan There is nothing to do to force the users to refresh the CSS/JS files. However, the only viable solution is to use versioning on the CSS & JS files.